# How to predict the standard deviation in linear regression?

Tags: regression, probability, bayesian, linear-model

When linear regression is formulated probabilistically using MLE, turns out that what we used to get as output, is actually the mean of $P(y|x)$, the latter is normal distributed around the correct output. My question is, can we also predict the standard deviation as well? so, for each $x$, I get mean $y$ plus $\sigma^2$.

My rough idea is, in addition to $h_\theta(x)$, we need $g_\theta(x)$ as our variance, and then $P(y|x) = e^{-\frac{(h_\theta(x_i)-y_i)^2}{g_\theta(x_i)^2}}$

Any reference for such derviation ?

Comment: The standard deviation of what quantity? Note that the standard deviation of the *error term* in the normal linear model is assumed to be constant.

Comment: @MichaelM Excellent point! Yes, the variance of the noise is assumed to be constant y=wx+epsilon. But can we make it variable and dependent on x (heteroskedatecity) and ask for it to be predicted?